# from where cordova plugin facebook pick facebook application Id ?

Tags: ionic2, cordova-plugins, cordova-facebook

i just run

```
 ionic cordova run ios
```

and got this in my package.json file there is some long integral key in APP_ID in place of "someKey" . my question is from where facebook plugin pick this app id ?

```
  "cordova": {
       "plugins": {
         "cordova-plugin-facebook4": {
            "APP_ID": "someKey",
            "APP_NAME": "myapp"
        },
        "cordova-plugin-device": {},
        "cordova-plugin-console": {},
        "cordova-plugin-whitelist": {},
        "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": {},
        "cordova-plugin-statusbar": {},
        "ionic-plugin-keyboard": {}
    },
```

Comment: during installation of the [plugin](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/facebook/) you didnt set the app id?

Comment: no @suraj  i just give command run ios

Answer (score 0, accepted):

cordova plugin picked the facebook application Id and secret key from config.xml file. it already saved there